# SwiftUI Image Opacity Animation affecting Other Views

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to build a list with progress bar and status icon. I want to animate the icon to indicate that some download activity is in progress. However, when I apply the animation, it also affects the progress bar and causes it to animate.

[image]

Here's the code for the list view:

```
List(syncProgres.downloadQueue) { mediaFile in
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Text(mediaFile.path).font(.callout).lineLimit(2).truncationMode(.middle)
        Spacer()
        ProgressView(value: Double(mediaFile.downloadedBytes) / Double(mediaFile.downloadTotalBytes))
        HStack {
            Text("\(MiscUtils.toHumanReadable(bytes: mediaFile.downloadedBytes)) of \(MiscUtils.toHumanReadable(bytes: mediaFile.downloadTotalBytes))").font(.footnote)
            Spacer()
            Image(systemName: "arrow.down.doc").opacity(opacity)
                .onAppear {
                    let baseAnimation = Animation.linear(duration: 1)
                    let repeated = baseAnimation.repeatForever(autoreverses: true)
                    
                    withAnimation(repeated) {
                        opacity = 0.2
                    }
                }
        }
    }.frame(height: 80, alignment: .center)
}
```

Comment: I mocked up a minimal example. I can't reproduce on Xcode 13RC and iOS 15. It must be something in the views you did not show.

Answer (score 0):

So swiftUI view modifiers work bottom to top, if the progress bar is getting the animation from the view below it add '.animation(.default)' below the view that you don't want affected.

```
List(syncProgres.downloadQueue) { mediaFile in
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Text(mediaFile.path).font(.callout).lineLimit(2).truncationMode(.middle)
        Spacer()
        ProgressView(value: Double(mediaFile.downloadedBytes) / Double(mediaFile.downloadTotalBytes))
            .animation(.default)
        HStack {
            Text("\(MiscUtils.toHumanReadable(bytes: mediaFile.downloadedBytes)) of \(MiscUtils.toHumanReadable(bytes: mediaFile.downloadTotalBytes))").font(.footnote)
            Spacer()
            Image(systemName: "arrow.down.doc").opacity(opacity)
                .onAppear {
                    let baseAnimation = Animation.linear(duration: 1)
                    let repeated = baseAnimation.repeatForever(autoreverses: true)                
                    withAnimation(repeated) {
                        opacity = 0.2
                    }
                }
        }
    }.frame(height: 80, alignment: .center)
}
```